# List of query result in a form and know the submit

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm try to do a WP plugin.

I have a *functions.php* and here have a function to know the name of the countries (`Select name_countries From Countries) to take only the names.

And I use the names to create diferents form with a button (more information), like this:

```
Spain |information|
France|information|
Italy |information|
```

```
foreach ( $pais as $pais) {
    echo "<form method='post' action='' id='form_paises'>";
    echo "<input type='text' id='v_name' value='".$pais->name."' placeholder='v_name' disabled/>";
    echo "<input type='submit' name='' value='Información' />";
    echo "</form>";
}
```

But I don't know how to send the name of the country to the function php to do a new select using this country to get more information of this country.

Comment: First of all, correct the `foreach` loop: `foreach( $pais as $val )` or another name you prefer **but not the same** (`$pais as $pais`)

Comment: Your question is unsuitable. We need more informations and more code. How you can pass the country name to the function? Maybe `function( $pais->name )`, but without seeing the function, it's only a bet. Do you have read wp plugin documentation?